# Sufficient conditions for Uniform integrability

Tags: probability-theory

Let $a_i >0$ be such that $\sum_i {a_i}^2 < \infty$. Define a sequence of random variables 
$$M_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i X_i$$. Now I am interested in knowing under what conditions (on $\phi$ and $X_n$)  $$\sup_n E[\phi(M_n)]< \infty$$
with $\phi$ satisfying the conditions of de la Vallée-Poussin theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Relevant_theorems).

I am looking for verifiable conditions which makes $M_n$ a submartingale as well as the above.

Comment: I think you should be a bit more precise about the type of condition you are looking for. One possibility is that the $(X_i)_i$ are in $L^2$ and pairwise independent (uncorrelated would be enough) and satisfy $\|X_i\|_2 \leq C$ for some $C$ and all $i$. In this case, we can take $\phi(x) = x^2$.